# Log onto Windows AD Domain via SSH using private key

Tags: linux, active-directory, ssh, private-key, plink

I would like to log into a windows domain from a linux box using a private key in place of username/password. I am using FreeSSH on the windows box and have no problems using keys for local accounts. I use plink to login to the windows domain and bypass the need for entering a password each time, but I do not want to store pw's on the linux box.

Comment: Remote Desktop allows you to save credentials so you can login remotely without entering a password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to logon to an Active Directory domain account with an SSH key in place of a username and password.